# Binding pattern for backgammon board game

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm implementing a wpf backgammon game ,
i need to find a pattern to implement the moves and positions of the pawns.

my board is combined of a grid with 3 rows : 
top-row , separator-row , bottom-row and 12 columns , the separator-row holds no 
functionality it is just a visual helper .

the top-row and bottom-row each consist of 12 cells containing a stackpanel ,
the pawns are presented as ellipses.

a movement in the game consist of removing an ellipse(pawn) from one stack and adding it to 
another .

```
  // Example move a pawn from stack23 to stack22 
  Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)Stack23.Children[Stack23.Children.Count - 1];
  Stack23.Children.RemoveAt(Stack23.Children.Count - 1);
  Stack22.Children.Add(ellipse);
```

i am required to use a predefined class for this project called **Board**

```
  public class Board
  {
     public Stack<Pawn>[] Pipes { get; set; }
     public Board()
     {
         Pipes = new Stack<Pawn>[24];
     }
  }
```

the pawn class provides properties for the game flow such as the owner of the current checker (player or the opponent)

```
 public Class Pawn
 {
     public bool IsMine{get; set;}
 }
```

each move would also consist of the functionality of popping and pushing from in the board

```
 Pipes[22].Push(Pipes[23].Pop());
```

(1)the UI and the functionality are separate because certain things have to be checked when moving a pawn ( though the ellipses are assigned different colors and could be checked by the colors )
but i have to use this class's any ways so i was just wondering what could be the advantages of decoupling the logic from the UI ...

(2) how could i implement a binding between the functionality and the UI 
how would , i bound the stackpanel to a stack and with what converter so that a pop and push operation would result in the equivalent UI Code?

Answer (score 2):

`(1) what could be the advantages of decoupling the logic from the UI?`

Exactly that. When your logic and UI are decoupled you can easily change the appearance of the UI without making huge changes to business logic and vice versa.

`(2)`

Use MVVM. Your current `Board` class is part of the Model.